# Guzzle SOAP request with wss headers

Tags: php, security, soap, header, guzzle

I need to set a new header for authentication in a Guzzle SOAP request.

```
$header = '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>' . $this->xiPayUser . '</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>' . $this->xiPayPass . '</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action 
                xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                Paymetric/XiPaySoap30/action/XiGGE.SoapOp</wsa:Action>';
```

Currently, I have this.

```
$response = $this->httpClient->post($this->configuration['xipay_wsdl'], [
  'auth' => [
    $this->configuration['xipay_user'],
    $this->configuration['xipay_pass'],
    'ntlm',
  ],
  'body' => $xml,
  'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction' => 'Paymetric/XiPaySoap30/action/XiGGE.SoapOp',
  ],
]);
```

How to transform the request to use the new headers and I think to remove the current auth parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question, the problem is a misunderstanding of the Guzzle library, in Guzzle we have the request headers that are the standard HTTP headers, and to send the SOAP headers we have to include it in the $xml we send into the parameter 'body' of the request, so in $xml we have to send the complete SOAP XML, in this case, I was authenticating the service using the SOAP headers, so I added the headers into the XML and removed the 'auth' parameter from the Guzzle request, also I had to change the content-type header to 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.